# Break all external links in excel using Python

Tags: python, excel

I have a excel file that has a few broken links (linking to some external files that have been deleted). Is it possible to delete these broken links in this excel using python libraries such as xlwings, openpyxl etc.

I tried using Range.Copy() in xlwings but that doesn't work either i.e. doesn't remove these external links.

Answer (score 0):

Before you proceed with a 3rd party solution, have you tried using the button in Excel's Data tab called 'Edit Links'? Seems Excel provides the ability to break broken links already. [Source](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/fix-broken-links-to-data-84f494f9-1da9-460a-aa83-aba07108bc97). After links are broken, the text "#REF!" will remain and you could use Find/Replace to put any other value in those spots.

Comment: Thanks, I am generating these excel files through the code which have to be later sent to intended recipients. Although, the solution you mentioned works manually , I am wondering if same can be done programatically (ideally from python)

Comment: I see. Are links broken on your own machine, or are you expecting the links to be broken after the file is received and the new owner opens the spreadsheet?

Comment: My code generates this excel file that has these broken links, I expect to remove these broken links before sending it to recipients. There are number of recipients, so doing this manually isn't feasible.